# TYPO3 Backend: Register new Ajax handler for 1:n records

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

By default, TYPO3 integrates a button to create new inline records, which loads a new empty mask. Is it possible to implement a "custom" button with its own functionality? E.g. returning multiple record forms instead of only one and pre-fill some of the fields?

[Ajax Handler button to create new inline relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTPhg.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can find and override (XCLASS) the core class which is responsible for those inline elements. But inline elements are a huge element in the core and and any modification can be followed by alot of unexpected behavior.
So I don't advice you to modify the core inline element feature.

So maybe you should DO IT YOURSELF. You can add a custom TCA field which is calling a PHP function to create your own button: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/User.html
Inside your PHP function you can also use the PageRenderer to include a **custom RequireJS script** to your backend: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Index.html

In your extension you can register an AjaxRoute which can be called from your RequireJS script: https://werkraum.net/devblog/detail/article/backend-routes-ajax-typo3-76/

The target of your own AjaxRoute is probably the function which will return your new inline elements which can be processed in your own RequireJS script.

After following those steps you probably have your own "inline record" functionality. Then you have to make sure that you persist your new elements properly.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. Seems like big effort, which in my case does not fit to project timeline. I decided to handle it by processing with my own data handler, generated new records on save...